# Scipy Sparse dot product with a 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I must perform a dot product between 2D and 3D arrays, which is working fine for numpy arrays. However when the 2D array is in sparse format, its `.dot()` method does not behaves in the same way, and throws the following error:

`ValueError: could not interpret dimensions`

Here is an example of such situation:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

Cshape = (36, 3, 101)
Pshape = (36, 36)

C = np.zeros(Cshape)
for i in range(Cshape[0]):
    for j in range(Cshape[1]):
        for k in range(Cshape[2]):
            C[i,j,k] = (i+1)*100+(j+1)*10+k+1

P = np.zeros(Pshape)
for i in range(Pshape[0]):
    for j in range(Pshape[1]):
        P[i,j] = i*j

test1 = P.T.dot(np.swapaxes(C,0,1))

P = sp.sparse.csr_matrix(P)
test2 = P.T.dot(np.swapaxes(C,0,1))
```

The test 1 will lead to the output I am looking for, the test2 will throw an error. How could I perform this operation in an efficient way without calling `.todense()` method ?

Comment: A `sparse.matrix` is, by definition 2d, a `matrix`.  `P` is sparse, so is `P.T`.  When used in P.T.dot(...)` it tries to do 2d matrix multiplication.  If the argument is also sparse, the result will be sparse.  If the argument is an dense, (numpy array) the result is also dense.  But there's no provision for handling 3d arrays.

Comment: Can you write the calculation as 3 dot products?

Comment: reshape `C` to (36,303), do the 2d calc, and reshape as needed.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to reshape ```C``` as a 2D array and reshape the output of the dot product.